# Doubts in parsing an xml file in android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

In my app I am parsing 1 main and number of supporting xml files. The tags of my main xml files are as below:

```
<subject>
    <chapter>
        <chaptername>A</chaptername>
        <pack>
            <packname>A1</packname>
            <packname>A2</packname>
        </pack>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <chaptername>C</chaptername>
        <pack>
            <packname>C1</packname>
            <packname>C1</packname>
        </pack>
    </chapter>
</subject>
```

When the first xml file is parsed, it lists the chapter names, and if I click any of the chapter names, it lists the pack names.

Now when I click on the pack name, I want the corresponding supporting xml file, which I have stored in the raw folder, to be parsed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at QueryPath for parsing XML in PHP. After you parse the information you can either pull in other XML files or XML strings from a database based on what the clicked tag is. Use jQuery for the AJAX part of it.

Sources:
querypath.org
jquery.org